# Docker daemon seems to ignore no_proxy configuration

Tags: proxy, docker, daemon

I'm trying to setup a docker daemon behind a corporate proxy (e.g. http://proxy.domain.name:3128) and want the daemon to ignore the proxy when pulling images from a local registry (e.g. registry.domain.name)

I have the following configuration:

File: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf

```
[Service]
Environment="http_proxy=http://proxy.domain.name:3128"
Environment="https_proxy=http://proxy.domain.name:3128"
Environment="no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,*.domain.name"
```

did `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker`

Symptom: Docker always uses the configured proxy and ignores the no_proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself ... *rolleyes*

`Environment="no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,*.domain.name"` is not properly escaped